# How to obtain log level through Serilog

Tags: c#, logging, serilog, seq, serilog-filter

Is there a way to obtain a log-specific log event level? For example, if I logged

```
Log.Information("This is information")
```

Could print out a value or somehow obtain what level the log was?

Comment: **Where** are you trying to get Serilog event severity levels? The `Log.Information` method just calls `global::Serilog.Log.Logger.Information` - there's no need for your code to intercept any of that.

Comment: I'm trying to just read the log level as it comes through, so for example if an application logs, I'd like to be able to read what the log level was.

Comment: "as it comes through"... why? I think you misunderstand how logging is meant to work... Also, why are you using Serilog directly instead of via MEL?

Comment: Okay so essentially the goal here is that I wanted to create a function that would filters logs based on whether the log level was low or higher/same as the minimum default level. I am very new to Serilog as it stands and I'm trying to understand how it works as a general.

Comment: To do that, use `LoggerConfiguration`'s `MinimumLevel` or `Filter.ByExcluding(...)` and other filters, see here: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics

Answer (score 1):

Probably, what you need is [Serilog Formatting Output](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output). That feature enables you to configure the log output as you want. For example, if you want to place the level and also the message in your log, you could do the following (remember to add in the project your Serilog Sinks dependency, Console in this case):

```cs
using Serilog;

namespace SerilogExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate:
                    "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss}] {Level:}: {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .CreateLogger();

            Log.Information("This is information");
        }
    }
}
```

the example above will print in `stdout` the following:

```sh
[00:30:35] Information: This is information
```

You could also use [custom formatters](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#custom-formatters) to a specific tool ingestion (`ElasticsearchJsonFormatter` for example).

Comment: I guess what I'm looking to do is get the log level from the log itself and then compare it to a specific applications minimum log level that is set through a configuration file. I'm going through this route because I'm not logging directly to any specific sink but to a middleman type server that filters out the logs.

Comment: Hello @GuyWhoLikesPlums, thanks for your reply. There are two approaches that you could follow:
1 - Filter the log level directly in your applications (no middleware is required): https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#minimum-level;
2 - If you want to apply the filter directly in the middleware, you could configure the `outputTemplate` as I've mentioned above, in JSON format for example (every log will have the same format and fields). The middleware will be responsible for deserialize the log and filter them as you want (for example, you could filter by log level).